# Find the minimum value of the sum CA+CB?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, maxima-minima, geometric-inequalities

> In a triangle $ABC$, the base $AB = 6 \mbox{cm}$. The vertex $C$ varies such
>   that the area is always equal to $12 \mbox{cm}^2$. Find the minimum value of the sum $CA+CB$.

My attempt: set $AB$ as a $base = 6$ cm;  after that I apply the area of triangle formula that is $area = (\frac{1}{2}) base* height = 12 cm^2$  and i got  $height = 4$ cm.
From that I find Right angle triangle ..I again apply the Pythagorean theorem .I got the value... $CB + CA = \sqrt{ 52} + 6$.
Is my answer is correct or not?

Comment: No. The right-angled triangle you used would give the answer $\sqrt{52}+4$, but there are other possible triangles with height $4$, and the right-angled one is not the one that minimises $CA+CB$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your way is not true. Why the minimum occurs for right-angled triangle?

I think we can solve your problem by the following way.
Let $CD$ be an altitude of the triangle and $BD=x$.

Thus,
$$CD=\frac{2\cdot12}{6}=4$$ and by Minkowski (triangle inequality) we obtain:
$$AC+BC=\sqrt{(6-x)^2+4^2}+\sqrt{x^2+4^2}\geq\sqrt{(6-x+x)^2+(4+4)^2}=10.$$
The equality occurs for $(6-x,4)||(x,4)$, which happens for $x=3$.

Id est, we got a minimal value.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

The locus of $C$ is two lines parallel to $AB$, one line lie above $AB$ by 4 cm, one line lie below $AB$ by 4 cm. We denote the upper line by $l$. We only need to consider the case when $C$ lies on $l$.

Let $B'$ be the reflection of $B$ along $l$, then $CA+CB = CA+CB'$, so  $CA+CB$ is minimized when $C,A,B'$ are collinear, which implies $CA=CB$, the triangle is isosceles in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider this triangle on the coordinate plane. Let A has coordinates (0,0) and B has coordinates (6,0). Point C will belong either to line y=4 or y=-4 but it's irrelevant, both cases will produce the same result. Let x be the abscissa of point C. We can define CA+CB as the following function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+4}+\sqrt{(6-x)^2+4}$. Now all we need to do is to find the minimum of this function when $x$ is between 0 and 6. $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} - \frac{x-6}{\sqrt{(6-x)^2+4}}$. Solving $\frac{df}{dx}=0$ we find that $x$=3. Now all we need to do is to check the values of $f(0), f(3), f(6)$ to prove that the minimal value is $f(3)$.